# Something about SSD

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

So, I read that a SSD requires ACHI for Communication. I checked my BIOS for that, and luckily I have it. My Question is that, suppose, if I buy a SSD that consists of 70 GB. And, suppose if I put only CS: GO in it and the Windows files in my old HDD. Will my computer run CS: GO faster than the previous drive, or Do I need to put those "Windows Resources" in SSD to make the game run faster, so I can have a smooth performance, or they'll work fine in just simple HDD?

I really don't care about the time my computer boots up, I just want better performance in my gaming zone like Just Cause 2, CS: GO etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you put on your SSD will be much faster than a traditional magnetic hard drive.  The load times on your games will be cut dramatically.  It is not necessary to put your OS on the SSD, however it Microsoft does recommend putting your pagefile on one, as it will increase performance, especially when switching applications.

Comment: And the Pagefile is round about how much? (size)

Comment: And can we just copy/paste Pagefile.sys to SSD, or there is a proper method for it?

Comment: No, the pagefile can be moved from the advanced tab of Computer proerties.